# How to disable script debugging in Visual Studio 2010 when running Asp.Net website project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm creating a website in Visual Studio 2010. I would like to use Visual Studio for C# debugging, without using it as JavaScript debugger. **Is there a way to disable script debugging for Asp.Net website projects?** I run my projects by hitting F5 in my Visual Studio.

(I've noticed that when I attach the debugger manually, I can specify the type of stuff I would like to debug.)

Note: **I would like to debug JavaScript, but not with Visual Studio 2010. The Developer Toolbar will suffice.**

Comment: Have you tried the solution I linked to?

Comment: @SirCripsalot - yeah... works perfectly, but I had to install the SilverLight SDK. I'm stupified :D.

Comment: The most ridiculous thing is that the bug has been closed on Connect with the reason "By Design"!

Comment: Sort of a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664208/ie8-and-vs2008-how-do-i-disable-script-debugging

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130809063147/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/468156/ie8-visual-studio-2010-and-script-debugging) on Connect, and the [other article](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/06/disabling-script-debugging-with-vs-2010.html) it links to.

To summarise, it's a workaround.  Apparently VS can't attach the debugger to both Silverlight and script so if you turn on Silverlight debugging, it has to disable script debugging!  To access these settings, go to **Start Options** which is within the web site **Property Pages**.

Comment: Wahahahha... amazing! I had to install the SilverLight runtime SDK (http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/) but it works fine!! Wahahaha... this this the funiest answer ever!

Comment: Updated with archive link.

Answer (score 7):

Just go to **Debug->Options & Settings** and select **Just-In-Time** and **Uncheck Script** from **Types of Code to enable debugging**.

***This will disable script debugging.***

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem on VS2015. There you can choose on which browser you run/debug project. I think older VS opens default browser, so you should change that.

Anyway, I set project to open in chrome and then I manually opened IE and copy-paste the URL from chrome. VS doesn't debug javascript in that case.

Answer (score 0):

On website project left click on project in solution explorer and go to the **project properties->go to the Web tab->scroll to the bottom of this tab and on Debuggers area** select ASP.NET and Silverlight checkbox. It will disable script debugging.

Answer (score -3):

If u r using IE 8.0 then go to tools-Internet options-advance tab- and uncheck Disable script debugging. Its works fine here.

Comment: I would like to debug, but not with Visual Studio. The developer toolbar is enough.