# How to suppress script errors in Visual Studio's embedded browser

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I'm using the embedded webbrowser in Visual Studio to look up API documentation while I work on my program that targets said API.

Unfortunately, there are multiple script errors on the website that I use. So whenever I navigate to a page, multiple warnings pop.

In my internet options, I've set the following preferences:

> [x] Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)
>
> [x] Disable script debugging (Other)
>
> [ ] Display a notification about every script error

But no matter what I do, I can't get rid of these f@#{[^@| popups

[image: help me]

I'm about to lose my mind over this. Please help.

**edit**

To clarify: this isn't an ASP project. I'm simply viewing a remote website in the embedded browser.

> View | Other Windows | Web Browser (CTRL + Alt + R)

This is the browser that opens when you follow a hyperlink in a file.

Comment: I think this link might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512225/how-to-disable-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-2010-when-running-asp-net-websi

Comment: @Richard I updated my question with more information

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem, this single line of code did the trick.

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```